# Get AzureAD/EntraID application properties from API call

Tags: azure-active-directory, azure-ad-graph-api, azure-entra-id

I am completely new with AzureAD and would like to use API calls to test that the configuration of the EntraID applications we are using are correct.
Our identity team created a service principal attached to the entraID application I would like to query. I used this service principal clientId, clientSecret and our tenantId to generate a graph client (see snapshot of python code below)

```py
        client_id = self.settings['clientId']
        tenant_id = self.settings['tenantId']
        client_secret = self.settings['clientSecret']

        client_credential = ClientSecretCredential(tenant_id, client_id, client_secret)
        graph_client = GraphServiceClient(client_credential)
```

Then to get my entraID application properties, I followed the step documented here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/application-get?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=python#request :

```py
result = await graph_client.applications.by_application_id('my-entraID-applicationID').get()
```

But it doesnt work and I get a `RessourceNotFound` Error:

```
Request_ResourceNotFound Resource 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx' does not exist or one of its queried reference-property objects are not present.
```

Do you know what I am doing wrong? (The app has been granted the API permission Application.Read.All, Group.Read.All,  GroupMember.Read.All)

Comment: There's a good chance you are using the wrong ID. You need the _object ID_ for API calls.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. I will contact my identity team and double check that I have the correct ID for my EntraID app

Comment: I just tried by using the object ID but still have the same exact error message but with the objectID referenced in it. Do you know if I am missing permissions? to query the object?

Comment: (using a service principal client id/secret pair attached to the app I am trying to query)

Answer (score 0):

> I agree with *@juunas*, the error occurred as you are using **Application ID** of Entra ID app registration, instead of Object ID.

I have one Entra ID application with `Application.Read.All` permission of **Application** type granted in it:

[image]

Initially, I too got **same error** when I tried to get application properties by passing Application ID like this:

```py
result = await graph_client.applications.by_application_id('my-entraID-applicationID').get()
```

**Response:**

[image]

To resolve the error, you need to pass the **Object ID** of Entra ID app registration that can be found here:

[image]

When I ran below python code by replacing Application ID with <kbd>**Object ID**</kbd>, I got the **response** with application properties successfully like this:

```py
import asyncio
from azure.identity import ClientSecretCredential
from msgraph import GraphServiceClient

tenant_id = "tenantId"
client_id = "clientId"
client_secret = "clientSecret"

client_credential = ClientSecretCredential(
    tenant_id=tenant_id,
    client_id=client_id,
    client_secret=client_secret
)

graph_client = GraphServiceClient(client_credential)

async def main():
    try:
        result = await graph_client.applications.by_application_id('my-entraID-objectID').get()
        print(result)
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)

asyncio.run(main())
```

**Response:**

[image]

**Reference:**
[Get application - Microsoft Graph v1.0](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/application-get?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http#http-request)

Comment: Thank you for your detailed reply, unfortunately I just tried by using the object ID but still have the same exact error message but with that time with the objectID referenced in it. Do you know if I am missing permissions to query the object?

Comment: (using a service principal client id/secret pair attached to the app I am trying to query)

Comment: You need to use object ID of **app registration** not service principal attached to it.

Comment: but can I use the client ID and secret of a service principal for the credentials step?

Comment: If you are using `az ad sp create-for-rbac -n my_app` command to create service principal secret, it will create secret in app registration only that works if you use it for credentials step.

Comment: Unfortunately this didn't solve my problem as I already have already done these steps. I am waiting to hear from specialist team . Will post the solution here if they find one

Comment: @Ihoupert Could you include Portal screenshot of what ID you are passing in your question?